# Changing all the html image src tags with non-existing src in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a jQuery problem. I want to loop through all the image tags and check image of src attribute really exists even it is not empty and set a default image if it does not really exist.

```
$('img').each(function(index){
    var url = $(this).attr('src');

    $(this).error(function(e){
        $(this).attr('src','default url value') //problem is here. I cannot change the current image src using this keyword
    })
})
```

The problem I realized is this

```
$('img').each(function(index){
    var test = '';      
    $(this).error(function(e){
        test = 'changed'
    })
    alert(test) //test value is always empty. That is the problem.
})
```

So why I cannot do that?

Why test value is never get changed?

Comment: Try this once `$('img').error(function(){
  $(this).prop('src','default url value')
 });`

Comment: That is how function scope works in Javascript. Move the alert into the error function and it won't be blank

Comment: From a usability perspective, this is very bad practice. I assume you have no other choice, and that you're simply trying to fix an old broken website, but if you can: fix this issue either on the back-end, or hard-coded. Just for the sake of search egnines and people without JS. (And performance wise, obviously.)

Comment: $('img').error(function(){ $(this).prop('src','default url value') }); this is working . I do not need outer loop . $('img').each(function(){  }) . Thank you so much. @Satpal

Answer (score 0):

The thing is when you are `alerting` the variable test, `onerror` event will still be executing. Because, onerror will take sometime to complete as it loads an external resource and your alert will exectue bofre the onerror will execute its callback function.

```
$('img').each(function(index){
        var test = '';      
        $(this).error(function(e){
            test = 'changed';
            alert(test);
        })
        alert(test);
    });
```

In the above code, you will see two alert popups one will be blank and after a few seconds you will see another one with the value `changed`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs in the following order:

```
$('img').each(function(index){
   var test = '';                //1
   $(this).error(function(e){    //2
       test = 'changed'
   })                            //3
   alert(test)                   //4
})
```

shortly after, the rest of the code is running as following:

```
$('img').each(function(index){
   var test = '';
   $(this).error(function(e){
       test = 'changed'          //5
   })
   alert(test)
})
```

You can try this to clear the problem:

```
$('img').each(function(index){
   console.log("1");
   $(this).error(function(e){
       console.log("3");
       test = 'changed'
   })
   console.log("2");
   alert(test)
})
```

and finally, you can try this that works fine: (add this code to the main page script tags)

```
$('<img/>', {
        error: function (e) {
            $(this).attr("src", "correct address...")
        }
    }).appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Also you can log Date.now() instead of log digits as following:
console.log(Date.now())

Comment: All is not working. The problem is every changes I made in the inner loop are not affected when the inner loop is over. I cannot reference to $(this) in the inner loop also.